# pocketsphinx excessively verbose

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now that I have pocketsphinx running well, I am launching it with a number of other nodes.  The basic pocketsphinx program prints many "INFO:" statements as it processes the voice input.  This makes any messages printed by my other nodes unusable since they scroll off the screen rapidly.

Not using "output="screen" when recognizer.py is launched only stops the messages from recognizer.py, not from pocketsphinx.

Can anyone tell me how to stop these messages?

Thanks,
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185563/pocketsphinx-excessively-verbose/) by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try playing with the `logfn` parameter:

E.g. from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825820/how-do-i-turn-off-e-info-in-pocketsphinx:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -logfn /dev/null
```

Or write to file:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -logfn [file]
```

In python (what ros pocketsphinx is using), from https://mattze96.safe-ws.de/blog/?p=640:

```
self.asr.set_property('logfn', '/dev/null')
```

---

Originally posted by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) with karma: 141 on 2015-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vikz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/25487/vikz91/) on 2016-01-06**:
This worked.. For windows Users, use pocketsphinx_continuous -logfn NUL